# WPF - RowHeaderTemplate align top an control when expanded

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I would like to align a control in `RowHeaderTemplate` to top.

This is how the control looks now:

[image]

And this is my template:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Background="Green">
            <Expander Background="Yellow" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

As you can see the `StackPanel` which has green `background` does not cover 'whole' template box , so I can't vertically align `Expander` to top.

Could you give me advice how can I solve this small problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with code behind. My `Expanded` method looks like this now:

```
for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
            {
                if (vis is DataGridRow)
                {
                    var row = (DataGridRow)vis;
                    row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
                    row.UpdateLayout();
                    var height = row.RenderSize.Height; 
                    var exp = sender as Expander;
                    ((StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(exp)).Height = height;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

And on collapsing i set `StackPanel`'s `height` to `30` ( because it is my default height )

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
[How to Center Align row numbers in Datagrid row header in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002079/how-to-center-align-row-numbers-in-datagrid-row-header-in-wpf)

This worked for me:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRowHeader}}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```